# What's the real signature of urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the docs it is

> urllib2.urlopen(url[, data[, timeout[, cafile[, capath[, cadefault[,
>   context]]]]]) Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a
>   Request object.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

But in the code of the module it is:

```
def urlopen(url, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
```

Is the documentation wrong or is the function instrumented somewhere?

Comment: What version of urllib2 are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the Python version.

The last line of the documentation of this function states:

> Changed in version 2.7.9: cafile, capath, cadefault, and context were
>   added.